# Gamma function in Taylor series

Tags: prime-numbers

The formula I am having some problems is this one
$$
f\left( x \right) =\sin  \left(\frac { 2(x-3)!-x+1 }{ 2x } \pi \right)  =\sin  \left(\frac { 2\,\Gamma (x-2)-x+1 }{ 2x } \pi \right)  
$$

Although this might seem too general it is a variation of Wilson's theorem which (in my opinion) has slightly better properties than the general Wilson's theorem formula.

If you look at the graph you'll see that the values for $f(x)$ where $x$ is prime is 0 while for $x$ nonprime tends to be converging toward $-1$ and in almost a perfect fashion and rapidly.
My idea is this: turn this into infinite Taylor series and add $x$ to it, that way we could get a good approximation of prime counting function to infinity.

In other words:

$$
\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ x+\sum _{ n\epsilon N  }^{  }{ f(n) }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \Pi (x) } 
$$

The problem I am having is actually converting it into Taylor series. I really didn't have any experience with this kind of equations so I was wondering is there any trick to do this, or should I just let this one pass

Edited: Changed the formula, forgot to multiply by $\pi$

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems I will answer my own question.
There is a similar formula that clearly says the nature of prime numbers and it goes like this:

$$\pi (m)=\sum _{ j=2 }^{ m }{ \frac { \sin ^{ 2 }{ (\pi \frac { { ((j-1)!) }^{ 2 } }{ j } ) }  }{ \sin ^{ 2 }{ (\frac { \pi  }{ j } ) }  }  } $$

This function really is a prime counting function but you can see that it is a little tricky to develop it into a working formula since it should be integrated over ${ 1 }_{ N }$ .

However since I'm already answering I'm going to show what I planned on doing with the formula:

$$\pi (x)\quad \approx \quad \sum _{ n=1 }^{ n=x }{ [\quad \cos { (\frac { 2*(n-3)!+1 }{ 2n } \pi ) } -\cos { (\frac { 2*(n-3)!+1 }{ n } \pi ) } \quad ] } $$

Comment: furthermore it converges toward $π(x)$